# Adding key fob access to SaaS for corporate customers

Tags: django, security

My company is creating a SaaS in Django. We know that some corporate customers will want enhanced security. We are already using https.

Would adding fob security (eg RSI) be a pain for what its worth? or is it over kill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that difficult to do - the framework comes with [authentication backend support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) ([dev material](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/authbackends/)) which allow you to customise what happens during the authentication process and provide multiple methods of authentication. We've used this to make authentication queries against other parts of our API; doing so is not impossible. The concept behind the backends is that the existing authentication code all "just works" and you turn on/off backends as needed.

One fob-like product I know of is called yubikey which was mentioned in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2311/2213); a quick google search turns up the [yubikey backend](https://github.com/Kami/django-yubico-authentication-backend) - never used it myself, however the code should give you an idea of how these things are done.

From a security perspective, some form of two-factor authentication adds an additional layer would-be attackers must defeat; be sure to look at how the scheme works. Something that just transmits a single determinable message can be intercepted, whereas schemes that generate one-use passwords add an additional hurdle, because although the attacker may gain access via session hijacking, having a varying scheme means the attacker must then know the next valid tokens.

Whether it is "worth it" depends entirely on the value of the information you're protecting. If you are protecting personal financial details of your customers, your trust/goodwill (and industry regulations) probably mandate you add extra factors. If you are building a web app so people can share photos of cats, probably not.

Comment: Ya, I realize the worth it part is totally subjective. But I guess what I really meant, was does it actually add more security, or is it one of those things that just adds extra friction with no benefit.